# How to allow deselection of a radio button with JetFormBuilder and apply a "pick up on site" status when no choice is selected?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a car rental website and I use **JetFormBuilder** to create my forms. I would like to know if it is possible to allow deselection of a radio button once it has been checked.

For the moment as an alternative I have added a radio button "on site pickup" that the customer can check.

And I want that when neither radio button is selected, I would like it to apply a "pick up on site" status for the vehicle chosen by the customer.